# PDO executing statement that mysql cli cannot

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database table with an unsigned int that represents a wallet balance. this column is called wallet. It is in a table called users.

The following query fails via mysql cli:

```
UPDATE users set wallet = `wallet` - 550000000 WHERE username = 'user'
```

With error message:

> ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in
>   '(`database`.`users`.`wallet` - 550000000)'

The issue is, when executed via PDO with ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, it brings wallet balance to 0 and continues execution without raising the mentioned error in an exception

SELECT @@sql_mode returns nothing in both the code and mysql cli.

Here is the function that creates my database handle and returns it to the query object

```
//This function connects to a database
public function connect($dbname,DBConfig $config = NULL)
{
            //If the connection is already set return it
            if(isset($this->dbs[$dbname]))
               return $this->dbs[$dbname];

            //If the config object is not already set, and still null, throw exception
            if(!isset($this->_config[$dbname]))
            {
               if($config === NULL)
                    throw new PDOdatabasesException('Database configuration object is not set',1);

                $this->_config[$dbname] = $config;
            }

                $config = $this->_config[$dbname];
        //Create a PDO object
        $this->dbs[$dbname] = new PDO(
                            $config::type . 
                            ':host=' . $config::$host . 
                            ';port=' . $config::$port .
                            ';dbname=' . $dbname,
                            $config::$user,
                            $config::$password
                        );

        //Tell the handle to throw exceptions
        $this->dbs[$dbname]->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $this->dbs[$dbname]->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

    //Return a reference to the newly created PDO object
    return $this->dbs[$dbname];
} //End connect()
```

Trying to save the need to paste a bunch of unnecessary code.. my query object takes a database handle from above, and prepares and executes this statement:

```
'UPDATE users SET wallet = wallet - ? WHERE id = ?'
```

binding the amount (approximately 10 million) and the user id, then executing.

Wallet balance can be at 0 and the query will still execute successfully. Why does this happen when the cli cannot? It does not make sense!!

I believe i need to once again reiterate **This query SHOULD fail if it drops wallet below 0!**

It succeeds through pdo, but not through mysql cli, my question is WHY??

Comment: Please run `select @@sql_mode` in both environments and report the differences here. Also, posting some relevant PHP code would not hurt.

Comment: The result of `wallet` - 550000000 should be less than 0 and your column is UNSIGNED.
Try to change your column type from BIGINT UNSIGNED to BIGINT

Comment: Updating based on user *name* is totally insane. Every user should be issued an immutable identifier number. That avoids people "inheriting" information from another deleted user with the same name.

Comment: That is completely unrelated to the question. in the actual executing query in the application it is executing by userid. The point of the question is that mysql cli is not able to execute what pdo is having seemingly no problem executing. I would like it to raise an exception with the error message provided in mysql cli.

Answer (score 1):

The result of wallet - 550000000 should be less than 0 and your column is UNSIGNED. Try to change your column type from BIGINT UNSIGNED to BIGINT

Comment: I am  expecting wallet not to be able to fall below 0. I would like the error that is mentioned in cli to be raised as an exception in PDO.. not for the query to execute

Comment: can you post your PHP script ?

Answer (score 1):

<s>This is apparently an unsolved bug in PDO::bindValue() and PDO::bindParam()</s>

EDIT:
I am apparently stupid and did not realize that data_type was REQUIRED to be defined when binding an integer to a query.

I have simplified the code to be the following:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1','omitted','omitted');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try{
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE test set number = number - ? WHERE id = 1");
    $statement->bindValue(1,1000000000);
    $statement->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

changing the statement to (and not using bindValue or bindParam):

```
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE test set number = number - 100000000 WHERE id = 1");
```

then the code throws the expected exception

CHANGING AGAIN TO:
    $statement>bindValue(1,1000000000,PDO::PARAM_INT);

throws as expected

Comment: I've just had this exact situation, I'm getting no exception when I'm using prepared statements, if I don't pass the parameters in, I get the exception. I hate PDO.

Comment: @Juddling Don't hate PDO. PDO is great!. This was actually my bad. Mysql wasn't really suppose to throw an error there, so PDO didn't raise. I needed to RTFM :)

Comment: Why don't you think MySQL should raise an error? I do like PDO, but changing the behaviour based on if paramaters are passed in? I don't like that at all!

Comment: @Juddling because mysql wasn't passed an integer. Mysql treats integers differently than strings. That is the reason why there are really only two PDO types. Computers are really bad about making educated decisions. One must be explicit.

Comment: There are 3 PDO types - `INT`, `STRING` and `NULL`. Also, "hating" PDO because you didn't read the manual is really useless statement, if you're fine with computer "reading" your mind, then you're fit to be a computer user - not a developer.

Comment: @steve here's my case, I still don't get an exception even if I pass it an integer: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KsMiLDjS

Comment: @Mjh I stand corrected. I forget about null because it is generally bad practice to store null, as it takes up the same amount of space as the column definition

Comment: @Juddling execute seems to default type to string. I bet if I check the manual it says that somewhere. But I could be wrong. Happened before :)

Comment: @Juddling " input_parameters

An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR
" -source PHP manual

Comment: @steve ah good spot thanks, I assumed (wrongly) they would have done some reflection on the array and bound that values with the correct type. Okay I like PDO, I just hate PDOStatement::execute() :D

Comment: I hate to be "that" guy who posts stuff people don't want to read, but having a `null` is far from bad practice. You can have foreign key relations, and having a null is allowed there, which means a record doesn't depend on another table. In that case, where you want referential integrity and an option to "soft" avoid it, `null` is extremely helpful.

Comment: @Juddling just because people don't like it doesn't make it a bug. Documentation was pretty clear about the functionality.